# C# Asp.net can't connect to phpmyadmin

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, phpmyadmin

I am building an appliciation that connects with a database. Now the problem is that i get an error when i try to actually connect to the database. *note, I know its not save, its for testing purposes only.

Also, when i go to the url given in `string server = "http://185.13.226.246:2222/CMD_DB/";` directly it will give me an error as in the picture below. But if I go to that URL indirectly (so via navigating) its fine.

It might be a very small problem but I can't find why it does not work.

edit: in the picture below there should be a list of available databases.

[image]

```
   public class DataConnection
{
    private static SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    public DataConnection() { }

    public static SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get { return conn; }
    }

    public void ReadyConnection()
    {
        string server = "http://185.13.226.246:2222/CMD_DB/";
        string database = "nickbbl114_atop";
        string uid = "bbl114";
        string password = "password010101";
        string port = "2222";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PWD=" + password + ";";

        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    public string Login(string email, string password)
    {
        string naam;

        cmd.CommandText = "Select Voornaam From persoon where email = '" + email + "' and password = '" + password + "'";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        ReadyConnection();
        naam = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        return naam;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how database connections work. It's going to take a long answer to field every point you've made, so I implore the community to please be patient with this one.

Answer (score 0):

you can create same database for any type of application either it's in JAVA or Dotnet or PHP.It doesn't matter.

First try to create a service layer in asp.net for Database CRUD operations. 1) EmployeeService - API service. 1.Insert a new record in the table. 2.Delete the record. 3.Update the record.

Sample to create service layer using WCF service - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254714/Implement-CRUD-operations-using-RESTful-WCF-Servic

The above layer can be used for both asp.net and PHP.

2)Asp.Net application - Call the above service using Jquery from asp.net application

3)PHP application - Call the above service using jquery from asp.net application